# Correct way to do 'if list in list' python

Tags: python, list

I taught myself python a little while ago and I find myself continually doing this piece of logic...

if any element of listA in listB then blah blah...

I would code this as:

```
for i in listA: 
    if i in listB:
        do something
```

Given the frequency with which I come across this I assume there must be a more efficient way of coding this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you wrote will "do something" for *all* items that are in both listA and listB.  Is that what you want, or do you want to do something if *any* items are in both listA and listB?

Comment: Your description and your code don't match. Do you want to `do something` once or many times?

Comment: Ahh yes I meant do something with i. For example, listb.remove(i). Thanks all, nice to know im on the right track :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function :).

```
if any(i in listB for i in listA):
    do something
```

This is assuming you want to do the `"do something"` *once*. if you want to actually do something with `i` (if it is in `listB`), then use the for-loop as you have done.

`any(i in listB for i in listA)`. is pretty much equivalent to:

```
for i in listA:
    if i in listB:
        return True
return False
```

Comment: Hi Haidro, as it turns out I was looking for a way to do the thing many times rather than once, sorry for badly worded question. Your answer is really useful though and help makes some of my other code nicer to read :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear if you need to do something once, or once for every element in listA.

So, if you need to do something once, transform them in a set, and see if the intersection is bigger than 0:

```
if (set(listA)).intersection(set(listB)):
    do something
```

If you need to do something for every element, skipping repeated values:

```
intersection = (set(listA)).intersection(set(listB))
for el in intersection:
    do something
```

And, if you need to do something for every element, regardless if its repeated or not:

```
for element in listA:
    if element in listB:
        do something
```

Comment: Is there any reason you need the second `set`?

Comment: @Gabe: There shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for i in list(set(listA).intersection(listB)):
    #do something
    pass
```